# Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition installed on my computer and I would like to start developing applications with SQL instead of MS Access.

What exactly do I need to install in order to achieve that?  Do I need a full version of SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio?

Should I just install MySQL instead?  I'm a bit lost...  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: There are free versions of SQL Server for Development (Express or Developer edition - if you have MSDN).

Comment: Thank you, Dave! :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Express Edition (with tools) is free, and perfect for development purposes. If you need more advanced features then you can use SQL Server Developer Edition which is very cheap and has all features included in the advanced versions of SQL Server. The licence does not permit you to run it in a live environment though.

Comment: Download can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=52679

Comment: Thank you, Laurence!  I will download and install SQL Server Express Edition then.  :)

Comment: You are also free to use Express edition in a live environment. If you ever outgrow the limitations of SQL Server Express, it's very easy to upgrade to a paid version of SQL Server. I see you are new to Stack Overflow. If an answer is useful to you, then please mark it as the Accepted Answer :)